# Turtlebot3 bring up from PC doesn't work

Tags: rviz, roslaunch, turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I am very new to this. I followed exactly(I believe) this http://turtlebot3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pc_software.html. I run roscore on my pc and launch on my turtlebot. When I tried to bring up rviz, by type in

```
export TURTLEBOT3_MODEL=burger
roslaunch turtlebot3_bringup turtlebot3_model.launch
```

I got this,

```
[turtlebot3_model.launch] is neither a launch file in package [turtlebot3_bringup] nor is [turtlebot3_bringup] a launch file name
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file
```

I checked all the package I had on pc, and there is indeed no turtlebot3_bringup. I am confused. I just expected it to work because I followed the tutorial closely.

How do I fix it? Maybe there is some small step I missed?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/267496/turtlebot3-bring-up-from-pc-doesn%27t-work/) by [rozoalex](https://answers.ros.org/users/31065/rozoalex/) on ROS Answers with karma: 113 on 2017-07-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to clone the turtlebot 3 github repository on your remote PC in addition to the tb3 shown in section [5.2.1](http://turtlebot3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pc_software.html).

The only thing you ever run on the tb3 is the bringup. Everything else, including RVIZ, SLAM, navigation, etc. is all done from the remote PC, hence you need to clone the repository to your remote PC.

Hope this helps!

---

Originally posted by [xnick77x](https://answers.ros.org/users/30994/xnick77x/) with karma: 77 on 2017-07-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rozoalex](https://answers.ros.org/users/31065/rozoalex/) on 2017-07-27**:
Thanks! Problem solved, I sourced the wrong setup file.